# Ruby on rails model with multiple parents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my Rails application, I have two models, Articles and Projects, which are both associated with a user. I want to add comments to each of these models. What's the best way to structure this?

Here's my current setup:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :project
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
  has_many :projects
  has_many :comments, :through => :articles
  has_many :comments, :through => :projects
end
```

Is this the right way to handle the structure? If so, how do I manage the CommentsController to have an article_id if it was created through an Article, and a project_id if it was created through a Project? Are there special routes I should set up?

One final comment: Comments don't always have to have a user. Since this if for my website, I want anonymous viewers to be able to leave comments. Is this a trivial task to handle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make `Comment` a polymorphic model. Then create a polymorphic association.

Here's an example of [polymorphic relationship](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/howtos/db-relationships/polymorphic) from the Rails wiki and here's a [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association) from the screencast-men Ryan Bates.

Comment: This seems almost perfect, but how do I handle the creation of a Comment? It's the Controller code that has me confused, and that example doesn't touch on it. For instance, say I have a form on a Project page to leave a comment -- upon submission, how do I associate the comment with that specific Project?

Comment: p = Project.find(...); p.comments.create(...)

Comment: You can use separate controllers for article comments and project comments.  Find the entity with which the comment is associated and create it in the controller through the entity's #comments association.

    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @project.comments.create!(params[:comment])

Comment: Duncan: So that would go in the ProjectsController, in a new action?

Comment: I added the link to a screencast.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out - acts_as_commentable plugin http://github.com/jackdempsey/acts_as_commentable/tree/master

Or you can proceed with polymorphic relation

Answer (score -1):

You could have `ArticleComment`s and `ProjectComment`s with similar structure but stored separately, then create a method that returns both types of comments.